# Mongoose Aggregate : limit the number of records in $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert this sentence using the Mongoose Aggregate method :

"For each player with given oid, select the game that has been played the most".
Here is my Game schema:

```
gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     game_name:{type:String},
     game_id:{type:String},
     oid:{type: String},
     number_plays:{type:Number,default:0},
    })
Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

Here is the code I am using :

```
var allids = ['xxxxx','yyyy'];
Game.aggregate([
    {$match: {'oid': {$in:allids}}},
    {$sort: {'number_plays': -1}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$oid', 
        plays:{$push:"$number_plays"}, 
        instructions:{$push:"$game_instructions"}
    }}
], function(err,list){
    console.log(list);
    res.end();
});
```

The code above returns the following:

```
[ { _id: 'yyyy', plays: [ 10,4,5 ] },
  { _id: 'xxxxx',
    plays: [ 28, 14, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] } ]
```

The problem is that it returns all games, not the one that has been mostly played. So my question is : is it possible to limit the fields populated in the $group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) to take values from the first doc in each group of a sorted pipeline:

```
var allids = ['xxxxx','yyyy'];
Game.aggregate([
    {$match: {'oid': {$in:allids}}},
    {$sort: {'number_plays': -1}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$oid', 
        game_name: {$first: "$game_name"}, 
        game_id: {$first: "$game_id"}, 
        number_plays: {$first:"$number_plays"}
    }}
], function(err,list){
    console.log(list);
    res.end();
});
```

Because you've sorted on `number_plays` descending in the preceding stage of the pipeline, this will take the values from each `oid` group's doc with the highest `number_plays`.