# MongoDB: Aggregate documents from groups by highest value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using the aggregation pipeline, I want to get the documents which represent the highest `price` for a `key`.

For example, take this collection:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"323232",
      "name":"Something",
      "key":"A",
      "price":"100"
   },
   {
      "_id":"157236",
      "name":"Another thing",
      "key":"B",
      "price":75
   },
   {
      "_id":"555232",
      "name":"Something or another",
      "key":"B",
      "price":78
   },
   {
      "_id":"83234",
      "name":"Something or another",
      "key":"A",
      "price":20
   }
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"323232",
      "name":"Something",
      "key":"A",
      "price":"100"
   },
   {
      "_id":"555232",
      "name":"Something or another",
      "key":"B",
      "price":78
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$key',
            maxVal : {$max : '$price'},
            others : {$push : '$$ROOT'}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : '$others'
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : '$others._id',
            name : '$others.name',
            key: '$others.key',
            price: '$others.price',
            pricecmp : {$cmp : ['$maxVal', '$others.price']}
        }
    },
    {
        $match : {pricecmp : {$eq : 0}}
    }
])
```

And this will be the output

```
{
    "_id" : "555232",
    "name" : "Something or another",
    "key" : "B",
    "price" : 78,
    "pricecmp" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "323232",
    "name" : "Something",
    "key" : "A",
    "price" : "100",
    "pricecmp" : 0
}
```

Comment: look like yours is more complete than my answer. thumbs up.

Comment: @ibininja thank you ! :)

Comment: Is there any way to project all fields without having to specify in the $project stage?

Comment: You can write `$project` like : `$project : { others : 1, pricecmp : {$cmp : ['$maxVal', '$others.price'] }}` But this will move all keys inside a subdocument having key name `others`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could return all the results  using a single stage. as far as my knowledge is extended the aggregate creates another collection with the result (hope others would correct me if I am wrong). You would get the max price and key and then use that to retrieve the whole document.

To get the max price for each key; here is how you do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $group:{ _id: "$key", maxprice:{$max:"$price"} } }])
```

**Update:**

The suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567496/mongoose-aggregate-limit-the-number-of-records-in-group) in the comment actually uses $sort with $match and it could work for you as well.

Hope that helps